# In JavaScript console.log

Tags: javascript, angularjs, concatenation

I'm having trouble with the JavaScript syntax. Why does this work:

```
console.log($rootScope.wg.variable1);
```

But this doesn't (says its `undefined`):

```
console.log($rootScope.wg.variable+1);
```

I tried some other syntax, but could't find one which is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this in a different way:

```
console.log($rootScope.wg["variable" + 1]);
```

The reason is, `variable1` is not the same as `variable+1`. This is nothing related to AngularJS, but it is basically how JavaScript's and other programming languages' concatenation logic works.

This is called as accessing `key` of an `object`, where `$rootScope.wg` is the object in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use access object by its `key` like below. Key can be concatenated as string.

```
console.log($rootScope.wg['variable'+1]);
```